# Parallelize array creation

Tags: f#, array-initialization

F#

```
[|for index in 1 .. items.Count()-1 -> (* create object here - complex operations *)|]
```

C#

```cs
Object[] newItemArray= new Object[items.Count];

Parallel.For(0, items.Count, index=>
{
    /*complex stuff here*/
    newItemArray[index] = new Object();
});
```

I have the above C# and F# doing the same thing.  Without the `Parallel.For` the F# is slightly faster.  With the `Parallel.For` the C# takes half as long to execute.  How do I properly parallelize the F# to get the same performance boost as the C#?

The way I've tried so far was `Array.Parallel.Iteri`, so I could use the same index into an array trick I used in C#, but it slowed it down instead of speeding it up.

**Edit:**

More details on what I'm doing:

I have an enumerable of `byte array array array`.  I have another `byte array array array` to which I'm comparing the others.  I'm sorting the enumerable on % similarity and returning the first 500.

In both the F# and the C# I'm doing a simple nested for loop which increments a counter.  When done looping over a particular item in my enumerable, I create a tuple of (item, counter).  Once done creating my new enumerable of (item, counter), I sort it on the counter variable, grab the first 500 and then convert back to just an enumerable of item.

The part which I'm putting inside the Parallel.For is the creation of the `IEnumerable<Tuple<item, int>>`

Comment: I guess it's time to start comparing IL...

Comment: I know it's not easy but can you give a reproducible example? You *Edit* doesn't help that much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use array comprehension in this case. It's a bit slower than high-order functions and can't be parallelized.

Though I would prefer @ildjarn's solution, here is an equivalent solution to your C# one:

```
// You need an uninitialized array to fill in later
let newItemArray = Array.zeroCreate items.Count

// Fill in the array in a parallel manner
Array.Parallel.iteri (fun i v ->
    (* create object here - complex operations *)) newItemArray
```

You can also use `Parallel.For` directly:

```
let newItemArray = Array.zeroCreate items.Count 

Parallel.For(0, items.Count, 
             (fun index ->
                 (* complex stuff here *)
                 newItemArray.[index] <- Object())
) |> ignore
```

It's more verbose but gives you more control over [degree of parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx).

Comment: `iteri` is the first method I tried and is only slightly slower than my sequential solution.  The `Parallel.For` solution takes about 3.5 times longer than my sequential solution.

Comment: Can you quickly compare parallel vs sequential solutions in F# Interactive with `#time "on";;`? It's hard to guess without more details.

Comment: I have a stopwatch around them.  Times are: 1.025 for the `Parallel.For` solution and .436 for the `iteri` solution.  My sequential F# solution runs at about .360 every time.

Comment: We need more details on the F# and C# functions. It's weird that F# versions don't scale when C# versions do.

Comment: @mydogisbox : Your edit does not have sufficient details, namely real code. Please see http://sscce.org/

Comment: I figured it out.  I was using some ref types to get around some parallelism issues and it turned out that was killing my performance.  Removed some of that and then used Array.Parallel.mapi and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

```
Array.Parallel.init items.Count (fun index ->
    (* create object here - complex operations *))
```

Official documentation: [Parallel.init<'T> Function (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee821138.aspx)

Comment: @pad : Not necessarily faster, just lacking in details. :-P

Comment: For some reason this takes 3x as long as my sequential solution and 7 times as long as my parallel C# solution.

Comment: @mydogisbox : You're profiling a release build, not debug, right?

Comment: Its release and "Start without debugging" with the "DEBUG" constant not defined.

Comment: To be clear, I'm using a `Stopwatch` to time the runs and then just printing the elapsed time to the console.